# quallity of the image will be bad after cutting the image and sending it on the server?

Tags: java, android, image, camera

I do not know , is the problem the cut function or the Decoding Code ? :
I use the code for for uploading:

```
public void Upload(View view) {
Bitmap Bimg = ((BitmapDrawable) image1.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
          // Bimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream); // bad too
         encodimg =  Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and i use this code to cut the image :

```
private void performCrop(){ 
    try {

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");

        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");

        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);

        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 512);


        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){

        String errorMessage = "Soory - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

[image: Show the different before between original capture and after cut and upload]
remark : I use a small image in xml as small preview :

```
<ImageView
            android:onClick="Load_Picture"
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:background="@drawable/default_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

but i do not thing, the image size in xml is the problem

Iget the Bitmap from Camera or From Galerie like that :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if ( requestCode==111 && resultCode==RESULT_OK  ){
        // Uri uri = data.getData();
        // imageView.setImageURI(uri);
        imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data"));
    }
}
```

the Problem is the cut methode , because if i upload the bitmap before cutting, i get very good quality. so the Problem is :

```
performCrop(){
```

Comment: We cannot see what you do with the cropped image.

Comment: `I use the code for for uploading:` That code does not upload.

Comment: `is the problem the cut function or the Decoding Code`. You mean the crop function? And the Encoding?

Comment: as example :
`cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 2028);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 1152);`
I get good quality only if I zoom the image max as possible before capture or by cutting i should select small space, else i get bad quality.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to send your cropped image to a server.

Instead you display the cropped image in an imageview. Then after that you take an screendump from that imageview and upload that to the server. Of course hat screendump has bad quality.

Instead you should upload the image you get from the crop function.

Please compare the resolution in pixels of all involved images.

Comment: yes, i get the bitmap as screenshot from imageview. what to do to get it directly from data? here is my code :
 `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if ( requestCode==111 && resultCode==RESULT_OK  ){
            // Uri uri = data.getData();
            // imageView.setImageURI(uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data"));
        }
    }`

Comment: I will not try to decode code in comments. Put your code in your post and give the info i asked for.

Comment: pls, check the 2 pictures above, why if i select small space i get good quality ?

Comment: You still have not posted he resolutions in pixels i asked for.

Comment: I use the front camera with high Resolution. but if the problem is resolution, why i get the same problem if i select picture  from storage from Galerie.
check the image of resolution which I ve added

Comment: I will check nothing. I ask you for resolutions.

Comment: my resolution is on code 512x512 and i have tested to use high resolution for example 2048x1152 and higher. the same problem